# Nokia Lumia 920 supports navigator.geolocation?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, nokia

I'm using the Javascript below to detect the geolocation service:

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Android, Apple prompts for geo location service whereas Nokia Lumia 920 doesn't prompt. Could someone please confirm whether I need to enable anything? Location detector is already enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the Nokia Lumia 920 runs an IE10 browser which does support HTML5 geolocation.

You can check this using the link on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp). Clicking the **try it** button, it prompted me for my location as you would expect. The site also helpfully provides the code.

The [HERE Maps API for JavaScript](http://developer.here.com/javascript_api) offers the `nokia.maps.positioning.Manager` which wraps this nicely and also works in mobile - try the example [here](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/map/positioning-the-map.html)